# What's the best way to consume messages in RabbitMq?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have about 100 different types of messages and I'd like to know the correct way to consume them in RabbitMq.
I have 2 solutions and I don't know which one is the best way.
1: Implement 100 consumers for 100 different types of messages.
2: Implement 1 consumer and process the messages by for example switch case or etc.

In your opinion what's the best way?

Comment: First of all you have to let us know what you mean by "the best way". Fastest? Most reliable? Easiest to understand? Then, you have to let us know if you can process the messages in parallel or if they have to be processed in order. Will these messages have unique headers or be published with a specific routing key?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be calling 100 different messaging services then you will need to set up 100 different consumers **BUT use only on rabbitmq connection**

Here is how I implemented my rabbitmq consumer

```js
module.exports.start = async () => {
    try{
      const queue1 = 'email';
      const connection = await amqplib.connect(process.env.QUEUE_SERVICE);
    
      const channel = await connection.createChannel();
      await channel.assertQueue(queue1, { durable: true });
      await channel.prefetch(1);
    
      console.log('Listening for emails...');
    
      channel.consume(queue1, async (msg) => {
    
        if (msg !== null) {
          winston.info(`Got message ${msg.content.toString()}`);
          const queueMessage = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
          Emails.Mailer(queueMessage)
          .then(() => {
            channel.ack(msg)
          })
          .catch(err=> err);
        }
      });
  
      const queue2 = 'sms';
      await channel.assertQueue(queue2, { durable: true });
      await channel.prefetch(1);
    
      console.log('Listening for SMS...');
    
      channel.consume(queue2, async (msg) => {
        if (msg !== null) {
          const queueMessage = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
          Sms.sendPaymentSms(queueMessage).then(() => channel.ack(msg));
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    }
      
    };
```

Another thing you can do to maintain code readability is to modularize the various services you want to call and call them in your consumer using conditionals or strategy design pattern.